# Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/dialog' - Angular upgrade v13 to v14 issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I upgraded Angular from **v13** to **v14**

```
ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14

ng update @angular/material@14
```

Getting this error after upgrade :

```
./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2015/dialog.mjs:1:0-93 - Error: Module not found: Error: Package path ./dialog is not exported from package D:\projectName\node_modules\@angular\cdk (see exports field in D:\projectName\node_modules\@angular\cdk\package.json)

Error: node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/index.d.ts:3:36 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/dialog' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { CdkDialogContainer } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
```

This is my **package.json** :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.1",
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure you have already installed angular/cdk.
If you don't have already installed, run the following command.

> npm i @angular/cdk

2.Make sure you have already import that CdkDialogContainer.
If you don't already imported, import the following code where your material module
imported.

```
import { CdkDialogContainer } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
```

Comment: Yes mate, I have @angular/cdk installed as mentioned in Package.json and about 'CdkDialogContainer' I'm not even using it in the app, If I try to import it to module, Angular Language Service displays same error "Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/dialog'"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinstall your node_modules, try these commands:

rm -rf node_modules

rm -f package-lock.json

npm cache clean --force

npm install --force

Answer (score 0):

npm i @angular/cdk worked for me while I was following this example https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview